# XFCE Session & Startup Application terminal command to turn on and off

Tags: linux, startup, session, autostart

In XFCE4 I can create my own custom start-up commands at *Settings Manager > Session & Startup > Application Startup* and turn them on or off by clicking on the command's check-box.

Is there a specific terminal command to turn one of these custom start-up commands on and off?